# Regex to match three groups of numbers

Tags: java, regex

How do I create a regular expression to match a string that looks like,

```
7440-44-0
```

where each group consists of numbers, groups are separated by hyphens, the second group (44) is exactly two characters long and the last group (0) is exactly one character long?

Here's what I tried, but I'm still learning regex.

```
Pattern.compile("[.\\d]-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{1}")
```

Comment: tries ??????????????

Comment: @vks I did try, just edited the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\\d+)-(\\d{2})-(\\d)$
```

Add anchors to stop partial matches.Use groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/54

Comment: Are those parenthesis for the groups necessary?

Comment: @jeemar no only if you want to capture each consittuent in groups

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried it out in the link you posted. Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
\d+-\d{2}-\d$
```

1. `\d+` - one or more digits
2. `\d{2}` - two digits
3. `\d` - a digit
4. `-` - matches *a dash* literally
5. `$` - at the end of string

A java escaped version:

```
\\d+-\\d{2}-\\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d$  or "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d$" as java string

Comment: It would be helpful to add more explanation